# Optional query string parameters in URITemplate in WCF?

Tags: wcf, query-string, uri, uritemplate

I'm developing some RESTful services in WCF 4.0. I've got a method as below:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test?format=XML&records={records}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public string TestXml(string records)
    {
        return "Hello XML";
    }
```

So if i navigate my browser to http://localhost:8000/Service/Test?format=XML&records=10, then everything works as exepcted.

HOWEVER, i want to be able to navigate to http://localhost:8000/Service/Test?format=XML and leave off the "&records=10" portion of the URL. But now, I get a service error since the URI doesn't match the expected URI template.

So how do I implement defaults for some of my query string parameters? I want to default the "records" to 10 for instance if that part is left off the query string.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Note: This question is out of date, please see the other answers.**

---

This does not appear to be supported.

However, Microsoft has been made aware of this issue and there is a work-around:

> You can get the desired effect by
>   omitting the Query string from the
>   UriTemplate on your WebGet or
>   WebInvoke attribute, and using
>   WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters
>   from within your handlers to inspect,
>   set defaults, etc. on the query
>   parameters.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/451296/

Comment: So that appears to work well. However, if I try to run the unit test against this, it no longer works since a unit test doesn't have a WebOperationContext. I looked up a few examples, but does anyone have a simple example of how to mock the WebOperationContext?

Comment: Try Googling "mock WebOperationContext". There are lot's of different ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 17):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781342/wcf-and-optional-parameters) this is fixed in .NET 4.0.  Failing to supply the query string parameter seems to result in its being given the default value for the type.

Answer (score 4):

Check this blog post out. Makes sense to me, and comes with a class to parse out the query string parameters.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2009/02/10/ambiguous-uritemplates-query-parameters-and-integration-testing.aspx

Basically don't define the query string parameters in the UriTemplate so it matches with/without the parameters, and use the sample class to retrieve them if they're there in the method implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work in WCF 4.0.
Just make sure to set your default value in your "Service1.svc.cs"

```
public string TestXml(string records)
{
  if (records == null)
      records = "10";

  //... rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, we still come to this scenario from time to time in recent projects.

To send optional query parameters, I created [WCF Web Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VanaCosmin.WCF.WebExtensions/) nuget package.

After installation, you can use the package like this:

```
using (var factory = new WebChannelFactory<IQueryParametersTestService>(new WebHttpBinding()))
{
    factory.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(ServiceUri);
    factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new QueryParametersServiceBehavior());
    using (var client = factory.CreateWebChannel())
    {
        client.AddQueryParameter("format", "xml");
        client.AddQueryParameter("version", "2");
        var result = client.Channel.GetReport();
    }
}
```

Server side you can retrieve the parameters using WebOperationContext:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters;
```