# WCF and optional parameters

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, optional-parameters

I just started using WCF with REST and UriTemplates. Is it now possible to use optional parameters?

If not, what would you guys recommend I do for a system that has three parameters that are always used in the url, and others that are optional (varying amount)?

Example:

```
https://example.com/?id=ID&type=GameID&language=LanguageCode&mode=free
```

- id, type, language are always present
- mode is optional

Comment: There is nothing special to be done. Just check for string.IsNullOrEmpty for the mode parameter and if it is null or empty, assign a default value.

Comment: I've the same problem, in .NET 4... There must be something to set somewhere... ANy hint?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I just tested it with WCF 4 and it worked without any problems. If I don't use mode in query string I will get null as parameter's value:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData?data={value}&mode={mode}")]
    string GetData(string value, string mode);
}
```

Method implementation:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetData(string value, string mode)
    {
        return "Hello World " + value + " " + mode ?? "";
    }
}
```

For me it looks like all query string parameters are optional. If a parameter is not present in query string it will have default value for its type => `null` for `string`, 0 for `int`, etc. [MS also states](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/451296/rest-wcf-uritemplate-optional-querystring-parameters) that this should be implemented.

Anyway you can always define `UriTemplate` with `id`, `type` and `language` and access optional parameters inside method by `WebOperationContext`:

```
var mode = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["mode"];
```

Comment: @John: Good question. I tried the `int` and edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Was getting confused cause I read about a lot of conflicting information regarding this.

Comment: I tried it earlier and it dint work, and now it works. Look at the question below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969238/optional-query-string-parameters-in-uritemplate-in-wcf

Answer (score 2):

I have tried with optional parameters in restful web service,
If we do not pass anything in parameter value it remains null. After that we can check for
the null or empty in function. If it is null then don't use it, else you can use it.
Let say I have below code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetSample?part1={part1}&part2={part2}")]
    string GetSample(string part1, string part2);
}
```

Here part1 is compulsory and part2 is optional.
Now the function would look like

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetSample(string part1, string part2)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(part2))
        {
            return "Hello friends..." + part1 + "-" + part2;
        }
        return "Hello friends..." + part1;
    }
}
```

You can also make the conversion based on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use "?" followed by "/" in your Url.

example:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetSample/?OptionalParamter={value}")]
    string GetSample(string part1);
```

Comment: This is the normal way of specifying a query string, and has nothing specifically to do with optional parameters.