# Restful WCF Default values

Tags: wcf, default

lyDefinition of the resource

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "getbydaterange/{insId}/{startDate}/{endDate}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<RestfulServiceObj> GetMyObjectsByDateRange(string insId, string startDate, string endDate);
```

How can i make the last two parameters optional? i.e, I want the bottom three calls to work

```
"http://domain.com/service.svc/myid/"

"http://domain.com/service.svc/myid/07-07-2011"

"http://domain.com/service.svc/myid/01-01-2011/07-08-2011"
```

But only the last call works, the rest give a missing parameter error.

Thanks
Bullish

Comment: What is your .NET framework version? [I tested this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781342/wcf-and-optional-parameters) with `string` and `int` parameter in `UriTemplate`'s query string and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you do so that same way you overload method calls:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "getbydaterange/{insId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<RestfulServiceObj> GetMyObjectsByDateRange(string insId);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "getbydaterange/{insId}/{startDate}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<RestfulServiceObj> GetMyObjectsByDateRange(string insId, string startDate);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "getbydaterange/{insId}/{startDate}/{endDate}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<RestfulServiceObj> GetMyObjectsByDateRange(string insId, string startDate, string endDate);
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I believe it gave an error that  can not have multiple methods associated with the uripath "getbydaterange".

Comment: @Bullish: Oops, change (or rather add) a **Name** parameter to the operation contract. e.g. `[OperationContract(Name = "GetMyObjectsByInsId")]`, `[OperationContract(Name = "GetMyObjectsByInsIdAndDate")]` & `[OperationContract(Name = "GetMyObjectsByInsIdAndDateRange")]`

Comment: Yup, that worked. Not what I was looking for but it's the closest.
Ideally I wanted one method and nulls getting passed to the parameters that were not being passed in.

Comment: @Bullish: You can still call the "full" method, passing null parameters in where you so chose from the stripped down method. i.e. Implement the first method with `List<RestfulServiceObj> GetMyObjectsByDateRange(string insId) { return GetMyObjectsByDateRange(insId, default(DateTime), default(DateTime); }`