# Optional UriTemplate parameter using WebGet

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have tried these

[Optional Parameters in WCF Service URI Template?
Posted by Kamal Rawat in Blogs | .NET 4.5 on Sep 04, 2012
This section shows how we can pass optional parameters in WCF Servuce URI
inShare](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9996/optional-parameters-in-wcf-service-uri-template.aspx)

and

[Optional query string parameters in URITemplate in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969238/optional-query-string-parameters-in-uritemplate-in-wcf)

But nothing works for me. Here is my code:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveUserInformation/{hash}/{app}")]
    public string RetrieveUserInformation(string hash, string app)
    {

    }
```

It works if the parameters are filled up:

```
https://127.0.0.1/Case/Rest/Qr/RetrieveUserInformation/djJUd9879Hf8df/Apple
```

But doesn't work if `app` has no value

```
https://127.0.0.1/Case/Rest/Qr/RetrieveUserInformation/djJUd9879Hf8df
```

I want to make `app` optional. How to achieve this?
Here is the error when `app` has no value:

```
Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have two options for this scenario. You can either use a wildcard (`*`) in the `{app}` parameter, which means "the rest of the URI"; or you can give a default value to the `{app}` part, which will be used if it's not present.

You can see more information about the URI Templates at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx, and the code below shows both alternatives.

```
public class StackOverflow_15289120
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveUserInformation/{hash}/{*app}")]
        public string RetrieveUserInformation(string hash, string app)
        {
            return hash + " - " + app;
        }
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveUserInformation2/{hash}/{app=default}")]
        public string RetrieveUserInformation2(string hash, string app)
        {
            return hash + " - " + app;
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/RetrieveUserInformation/dsakldasda/Apple"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/RetrieveUserInformation/dsakldasda"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/RetrieveUserInformation2/dsakldasda"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stumbled across this a couple years after the fact, helped me out today. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar scenario for below service method:
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "upload?fileName={fileName}&filePath={filePath}&replace={replace}")]
        void UploadFile(Stream fileContent, string fileName, string filePath, bool replace);
Here I need to have filepath and replace to be optional but above solution doesn't work for me (tried both, i.e. {*filepath} or {filePath=default}. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

A complementary answer regarding default values in `UriTemplate`s using query parameters. The solution proposed by @carlosfigueira works only for path segment variables according to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Only path segment variables are allowed to have default values. Query string variables, compound segment variables, and named wildcard variables are not permitted to have default values.